# Any reason not to share Azure Front Door between domains/environments?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I am looking to implement Azure Front Door for multiple web applications and across multiple environments (dev/test/prod). [Azure Front Door pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/frontdoor/) is a fixed fee of $35/month for Standard tier plus data transfer costs. Within the Front Door instance you are able to create multiple endpoints with each mapped to its own custom domain and origin group. I tested this and I'm able to route two separate domains into Front Door and then each out to separate app services.

I could create a separate Front Door instance for each application and each environment, but is there any reason not to just use a single Front Door instance to take advantage of the fixed fee pricing?

Comment: I am also looking for a similar set up. But I am facing challenges since I want to automate deployment. I thought of having one FD instance for all my non-production and one for my production. But there is no way I can add just backend pools and routing rules in classic FD per environment param file. It overrides the setting. Also it seems for standard FD you need parent relationship between origin groups and fd, end points and fd and so on...

Comment: If you do not want to automate easiest way is to have Front door manually set up and you can add routing rules backend pool (classic front door) or origin group, end point and route (standard front door). Premium base price is 10X the standard so I stay away.